# Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal in qtp

Tags: testing, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft

in a certain scenario, i was trying to use the select query inside QTP (More specifically QTP Using VB script) 
But the code is not working.

```
Option Explicit
Dim con,rs
Set con=createobject("adodb.connection")
Set rs=createobject("adodb.recordset")

con.open "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=myServer; Uid=USERNAME;Pwd=PASSWORD;"
rs.open "SELECT B.STATUS FROM STUDENT B WHERE B.BATCHCODE='FIRST' ",con

Do while not rs.eof
DataTable.GlobalSheet.AddParameter.RawValue = rs.fields("v1")
rs.movenext
Loop

Release objects
Set rs= nothing
Set con= nothing
```

Please help me knowing which section of the code is getting script result fail.

Comment: Is the problem in the query or in the `DataTable`? Have you tried using a vbs file to see if the problem is related to UFT?

Comment: Comment not clear.. can you elaborate?? 
or let me know if u need some more input from my end. (I'm new to UFT and VB scripting)

Comment: What is not working? Try to isolate the minimal code that doesn't work, then see if it's UFT specific or a problem with your VBS code. You can do this by putting the code in a .vbs file and executing it.

Comment: okiee, I'll try the same and let u know... thanks in advance :)

Comment: okiee... i have tried debugging the code, and the problem starts from the following line: 

`con.open "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=myServersIPAddress; Uid=USERNAME;Pwd=PASSWORD;"`

also, i have added a watch for the same and found that there are 2 objects in the Error Tab for variable con.

Answer (score 17):

"Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name" - this error comes when the field is not present in the recordset which you are trying to refer to!

rs will not have "v1" and it has only "STATUS".

```
  rs.fields("v1")
```

So, it should be

```
rs.fields("STATUS")
```